# Java- Obtaining bold text in HTML

Tags: java, jsoup

I am tasked with obtaining pricing information from online tables that update periodically. Specifically, the items listed in bold indicate the items whose prices have been recently updated. I am mainly responsible for those, and am to transfer those items’ information into the company’s database. However, I am a bit new to using HTML tables in Java and am unsure of how exactly to filter the bold items. I do notice they have the "strong" tag around them; I am just unsure of how to make use of it. I have tried Googling this extensively but almost all questions I find are about writing to an HTML table instead of reading from it. What I have found related to my question is a lot of recommendations to use either Jsoup or jQuery. Are these necessary for what I want to do (or at least make it significantly easier)?

Here is the code I have so far for one of the tables if it helps, although all it currently does is display the HTML for the entire table.

```
package cmtabacosPrecios;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
public class CeutaYMelilla_Cigarillos {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    // Run the getHTML method
    try {
    getHTML("http://www.cmtabacos.es/wwwcmt/listaPrecios.php?&zona=cm&labor=cillos&mostrar_codigo=S");
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error. Exception has occured.");
    }

    }
    // The getHTML method
    public static String getHTML(String URLToRead) throws Exception {
        URL cmtabacosPrecios = new URL(URLToRead);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(cmtabacosPrecios.openStream()));

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();

        // Return HTML as a String
        return inputLine;

    }
}
```

Comment: if you don't want to use jQuery then why you have added jquery tag?

Comment: My apologies. I am just new to asking questions here and I thought maybe it would get me a faster answer on whether or not I should use it.

Comment: Well, jQuery is going to be dramatically different in opearation to what you currently have. It would run client-side and do the DOM parsing for you (it's really easy), but then you'd need a way to get the extracted value, which would means you would need some way of exposing your Java application to the Internet, and then you can to an AJAX POST to it. However, I would assume this is not an option, as you seem to want to fetch a page and do static analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Below is exemplary code which retrieves data from your table using jsoup. Just modify it to get data which are important to you. You can also learn more about `jsoup` at [project website](http://jsoup.org/) it's really simple and powerful.

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.cmtabacos.es/wwwcmt/listaPrecios.php?&zona=cm&labor=cillos&mostrar_codigo=S").get();
        Elements tableRows = doc.select("tr");
        for (Element row : tableRows) {
            Elements marca = row.getElementsByClass("marca");
            Elements pvpExp = row.getElementsByClass("pvp_exp");
            Elements pvpPvr = row.getElementsByClass("pvp_pvr");

            if (!marca.isEmpty() && !pvpExp.isEmpty() && !pvpPvr.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println(marca.get(0).text());
                System.out.println(pvpExp.get(0).text());
                System.out.println(pvpPvr.get(0).text());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You, sir, are a lifesaver. If I understand correctly (there is a good chance I do not haha), would I use one of the Elements methods to display any text that has the "strong" tag wrapped around it? That is largely what I need to do. Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes, in this case you can use `Element#text()` (Element, not Element*s*) method to display what `<strong>` tag contains. Keep in mind that you probably need to know in which row you are, so the main loop in `tableRows` is needed.